# in KDE under Konsole, when re-opeing a crashed bash shell, how to control what /dev/pts/nn number it gets?

Tags: bash, shell, kde, history

I use Kubuntu 20.04 and KNOPPIX 9.1, and always the KDE desktop, and under Konsole 15 windows with shell bash in each.

I always have two levels of bash: the first level which automatically is created for user, e.g. knoppix, and a second level, which I create for user "root".

The windows and the shells in them have two essential names with attached numbers, e.g. "Konsole-2", "/dev/pts/1".

When it happens that a bash crashes, the bash vanishes without writing its history list to the history file.

And the window of Konsole is closed.

In order to restore the former state, I open a new window under Konsole, a shell become running etc.

Now the essential events:

Most often good ghosts make sure that "Konsole-n" and "/dev/pts/nn", resp., after restore have the same numbers as before crash.

This causes that bash has again the history list of state before crash. So I can continue my work.

But today, as it very seldom happens: "Konsole-n" has the same number as before of crash, but "/dev/pts/nn" is a totally different number. It is a nummber from some tests 2 weeks ago. An the history list is that of the former tests.

So I am in need: how can I acchieve a new creted shell bash to get the number "/dev/pts/nn" of before the crash.

It may be that my update actions had caused that the pts numbers are intentionally not repeated but taken new numbers.

Regards, 21.01.2023 21:32

== 30.01.2023 12:53
this question has a follow-up question in:

[Linux: How to access, resp. use, running processes, especially process bash, which are not attached to a terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1765726/linux-how-to-access-resp-use-running-processes-especially-process-bash-whi)

Regards

== 14.03.2023 22:00 new good report: good ghosts had reestablished my system :: I was working in in the window the tab of which was in the tab bar = window select bar on the third position from the LHS. The title bar showed "Konsole 3". The pseudo terminal number was 16, i.e. /dev/pts/16. As usual, I was not in the first-level shell of UID 1000, but in the second-level shell bash of user "root", UID 0.

It happened a crash (as often, I do not know why). Both levels of shell closed automatically, and the window closed, vanished. In the tab bar at botton the number of tabs decreased by one.

Now I have had to restore the situation.

I right-clicked on one window tab in order to get the context menu. I cklicked on "open new window". A new window opened. A new window tab was created, on the extreme RHS.

The first-level shell bash was invoked automatically, as usual.

The new window has in the title bar "Konsole 3", same as before the crash.

The pseudoterminal is /dev/pts16, same as before the crash.

I crated the second-level shell for "root": window has in the title bar "Konsole 3", pseudoterminal is /dev/pts16, same as before the crash.

And the important point: the history list of bash is there again, as before the crash, about 400.000 lines.

Thus this kind of behavior is back again. Kind of behavior as I am used since many, many years, a behavior which is in contrast to some answers I got.

Please does someone know the relationships, does someone comprehend this

Regards.

Comment: If I were you,I would be looking to why `bash` crashes rather than mucking about with pts's. This is an `X-Y` problem. The kernel handle the pts allocation.

Comment: == 14.03.2023 23:50 the crash that happened today was not caused by one of  the bash levels. It was probabpy caused the mouse pointer wandering around. The windows are very, very volnerable to be killed. Regards.